# Radio Button validation angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to disable the submit button,if radio button is not selecetd.Provided that radio button generates dynamic data from controller using ng-repeat in angularjs

Comment: Hard to tell what's the problem exactly, but docs have a good example https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Answer (score 1):

I used `ng-required="true"` on inputs. And it worked.
Take a look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NF5j2VC6prUCjRIk5bLW?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-required on the radiobutton and in the submit button ng-disabled

http://plnkr.co/edit/h7FJljOXSaEjkKZ9L3S9?p=preview

Take a look at the ng-required and ng-disabled directives in this code:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
   <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red" ng-required="!color">  Red <br/>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="green" ng-required="!color"> Green <br/>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="blue" ng-required="!color"> Blue <br/>
   <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
   <button 
   data-ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"
   type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: almost but not working please double check your plnkr

Comment: How this plunkr works: if no radiobutton is selected submit button is disabled, if you select one of the options the radio buttons get selected is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Well the question is: How to disable the submit button,if radio button is not select, nothing about showing an alert ;-)

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/lPOAaddGNBBOd8c9sWj2?p=preview

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
       <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red" >  Red <br/>
       <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="green" > Green <br/>
       <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="blue" > Blue <br/>
       <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
       <button 
       data-ng-disabled="!color"
       type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

js:

```
 angular.module('radioExample', [])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.color = '';
       $scope.specialValue = {
         "id": "12345",
         "value": "green"
       };

       $scope.submitForm = function() {
         alert('valid');
       }

     }]);
```